# get attr svg polyline

Tags: svg, polyline

html

```
<svg>
  <polyline points="0,0 100,100" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
```

jquery

```
 $("svg").css("width",$(document).width());
        $("svg").css("height",$(document).height()-10);
    $("polyline").click(function(){

        alert($(this).attr("points"));

    });
```

result

<-- alert -->

object SvgPointList

Question

How to get attr svg points?

Comment: Is this jQuery? If so what version? Seems to work just fine for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/YJQ3c/.

Answer (score 0):

why not try getting 'points' attribute using simple javascript

**i am giving id to polyline**

```
<polyline id="polyline_1" points="0,0 100,100" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
```

**now Javascript:-**

```
var polyline =document.getElementById('polyline_1');
var points=polyline.getAttribute('points');
```

it will return string.